# Testing for Remoting in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, remoting, powershell-remoting

I have a script that retrieves certain event log entries from a list of computers. I'm using a foreach loop over the list of computers with Get-EventLog -Computername $c... to get the events. I use Test-Connection MyComputer -Quiet to make sure each computer is up. I can't figure out how to test programmatically if Remoting is enabled. I've tried

if (!(Test-WSMan MyComputer))

that still throws an error trying to connect to Remoting to test if Remoting is enabled. Seems like a Catch-22. You can only test if Remoting is enabled by connecting to Remoting and if it's not enabled you get an error.

I also tried wrapping it in a Try...Catch but that didn't catch the error.

Is there a way to check from within a script whether or not a computer has Remoting available?

Note: I'm running PowerShell 4.0 everywhere PowerShell is installed.

Comment: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: You should add that as an Answer so I can mark it. This is much simpler. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to suppress error message, then `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` should en enough for you:

```
if (!(Test-WSMan MyComputer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
```

Or you can use `-ErrorAction Ignore`, if you does not want to add error to `$Error` automatic variable.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use this Function:

```
Function Test-PSRemoting
{
Param($Computer)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    Try 
    {
        if ((Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {1}) -eq "1")
        {
        return $true
        }

            else
            {
            return $false
            }
    }

    Catch
    {
    return $false
    }

}
```

Use it like this:

```
Test-PSRemoting ComputerName
True
```